# Lambda Netbeans 7.4 JavaSE 8 Build 99 throws Error: Could not find or load main class

Tags: java, netbeans

i have download `Netbeans 7.4 Beta version` which have `J2SE 8 Support` according to https://netbeans.org/community/releases/74/relnotes.html as well `jdk-8-ea-bin-b99-windows-x64-18_jul_2013` install Java later Netbeans using the latest Java JDK everything was working smoothly i create a project later a class a main method code

```
System.out.println("running java 8");
```

and it works but lately i try to run my first simple Lambda and throws

```
Error: Could not find or load main class javase8.JavaSE8
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

i download the netbeans only the JavaSE version only for JavaSE8 testing but dont works..

i have try to `clean and build` change the `directory of the project` `clean the cache` `Restart Netbeans` and nothing happens. I haven't able to run my first Lambda what is wrong this is driving me nuts..

here is my simple code.

```
package javase8;
public class JavaSE8 
{    
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
     System.out.println("running main."); 
     Runnable r = ()->{System.out.println("running runnable...");};
     //Thread t = new Thread(r);
     // t.start();       
  }    
}
```

if i remove the line

```
Runnable r = ()->{System.out.println("running runnable...");};
```

it works.

This lamdba expresion is created by Netbeans compiler itself after a anonymous inner class

the project on `Run` is enable to run under JavaSE8 as well their `source` `Binary Format.`

i have posted a video to show what i am doing please take a look.
[Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1lh6wO8nsdw&feature=youtu.be)

Comment: NetBeans 7.4 and even JDK8 isn't released. BTW try a nightly build of NB

Comment: Netbeans 7.4 beta version have JavaSE 8 support.